# Get Count in mysql query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I wants to select the count of votes got for each items.Following query works fine but there is a problem if there is no vote for an item then that item is not showing in result.I actually wants details of each items and votes.If there is no vote for an item it should be shown count zero.
How can i achieve it?

```
DB::table('wonders')
        ->leftjoin('vote','votes.wonderId','=','wonders.id')
        ->select('wonders.id','wonders.title',DB::raw('count(votes.vote) as votes'))
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DB::table('wonders')
            ->leftjoin('vote','votes.wonderId','=','wonders.id')
            ->select('wonders.id','wonders.title',DB::raw('ifnull(count(votes.vote),0) as votes'))
            ->groupBy('wonders.id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to use iffnull,try this

```
DB::table('wonders')
        ->leftjoin('vote','votes.wonderId','=','wonders.id')
        ->select('wonders.id','wonders.title',DB::raw('ifnull(count(votes.vote),0) as votes'))
        ->get();
```

Comment: No effect the same result is getting .It only returns the items having atleat 1 vote

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB::table('wonders')
    ->leftjoin('vote','votes.wonderId','=','wonders.id')
    ->selectRaw('wonders.id','wonders.title',count(votes.vote) as votes)
    ->groupBy('wonders.id')
    ->get();
```